# Unable to connect MySQL with powerBI even though I installed connector

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, mysql-connector

On my **Windows 11**, I downloaded Power BI today in order to pull data from MySQL.

I got the error "This connector requires one or more additional components to be installed before it can be used" while importing data

I have tried several versions of MySQL Connector/NET like **8.0.26, 8.0.28, 8.0.29, 8.0.30, 8.1.0, 8.2.0, 8.3.0**

But still, I am getting the **same error**

Comment: try https://help.scalegrid.io/docs/connect-mysql-to-powerbi

Comment: Still not working!

Comment: what is the error message ? are you sure the mysql server is correctly configured?

Comment: The error message is still the same "This connector requires one or more additional components to be installed before it can be used". 

Yes, I checked my MySQL twice. Its properly configured.

Comment: i can not reproduce your problem, i installed powerbi fresh from the app store and installed the last mysql connetor and i can connect to a local server on port 3306

Comment: I did the same. I even uninstalled MySQL and downloaded it again.

No worries, Thank you for trying, I appreciate it.